# jqGrid client-side Internationalization

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am using a JSON object to populate the jqGrid jQuery plug-in.

I would like to internationalize the currency format from this JSON object on the client side.  Is this possible with jqGrid?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that jqGrid has a column-specific setting called "[formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter)."  This could be used to adjust currency and the like.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I posted [the feature request](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/small-changes-in-i18ngrid-locale-xx-js-files-to-make-possible-dynamic-language-switching/) which include [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Localization1.htm). The code shows how you can with respect of small change in the grid.locale-XX.js to allow to load many languages on the client size. Additionally I show how to make the language choice based on the language of the web browsers `(navigator.language || navigator.browserLanguage`). If you use the standard [predefined formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apredefined_formatter#predefined_format_types) the date or currency will be formatter as needed.

The changes which I suggest in [the feature request](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/small-changes-in-i18ngrid-locale-xx-js-files-to-make-possible-dynamic-language-switching/) are very simple and you can do this yourself. By the way the changes allows the client user to switch jqGrid language (locale) even dynamically.

Additional problem with currency is that you will have to recalculate the values based on the currency conversions. If you know the source currency and the destination currency (from the local) you can do this for example inside of the `loadComplete` function. You can use of course [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter) but you will have to solve the same problems.